# Identify artist of tapestry

Tags: seal

I am try to identify the artist or school of art for a silk tapestry by their seal:

[image]

Comment: the seal says 長壽

Comment: Who is that, I don't recognize the name.

Comment: 長壽 means 'long life'. It doesn't seem like a name.  More like a  'blessing' message ( like a decoration) . The artist's name is not there because this is a  mass production product made by craftsmen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

title: 松龄鹤寿, pine's age and crane's life. seal: 长寿, long life。There is not any artist information.